# A function that creates a partition of values such that the sum is 1

Tags: special-functions

I'm trying to find a function $g:\mathbb N\cup\left\{0\right\} \rightarrow\left(0,1\right)$, such that, given a (real) value $k \in \left(0,1\right)$ and an integer $i>1$, allows me to calculate a partition of the interval $(0,1)$ that fulfills the following conditions:

1. $k$ is a parameter of the function.
2. The function only has a positive value if $0 \leq j\leq i$, and zero on every other case.
3. The sum of the function results for every $j \in \left\{ 0,1,\dots,i\right\}$ is 1: $$\sum_{j=0}^{i}g_k\left(j\right)=1$$
4. For every $j \in \left\{1,\dots,i\right\}$:$$g_k\left(j\right)=k·g_k\left(j-1\right)$$

Condition (3) implies the following: $$\underset{k\rightarrow1}{\lim}g_k\left(j\right)=g_k\left(j-1\right)\ ,\ j\in\left\{ 1,2,\dots,i\right\} $$

I know such function exists, but I don't remember the function (and I don't find any reference to it), and I've been struggling with this for some time.

Could you point me in the right direction? (a name for such function would be enough)

Comment: When you say $g(j)$, do you mean $g(x_j)$, where $x_j$ are the terms of some partition of $(0,1)$?  Or do you mean the actual integers $1,\dots,i$ (none of which are contained in $(0,1)$?

Comment: @Donkey_2009 No, I mean exactly the natural numbers... I'm editing the question to make it more clear

Comment: When you talk about the limit as $k\to 1$, what topology are you taking on the natural numbers?

Comment: $k$ is a real number in the interval $(0,1)$

Comment: OK, that's right.  But then $\lim_{k\to1}g(j)=g(j)$, since $g(j)$ doesn't depend on $k$ at all.

Comment: duh, right! Forgot to write that $k$ is a (deterministic) parameter of the function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to find $g(0)$, for then $g(i)=k^ig(0)$  You have a [geometric series](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series), so $$\sum_{j=0}^{i}g\left(j\right)=\sum_{j=0}^{i}g(0)k^j=g(0)\frac {1-k^{i+1}}{1-k}=1\\g(0)=\frac {1-k}{1-k^{i+1}}$$

Comment: Thank you!!! Do you know is this function has some special name (other than geometric series)? (I know I found it in a book some years ago, but I can't remember the name... or the book)

Comment: I don't know of one